# problem with setting a cookieless domain

Tags: php, cookies

Here is the header from firebug that shows the scope of the PHP Session cookie:

**Set-Cookie**   PHPSESSID=f0e2dfe56cc78be718c8154ac80d1ae2; path=/; domain=pix-all.com

But still the PHP Session cookie is been sent for any requests to static.pix-all.com

**Cookie**  PHPSESSID=f0e2dfe56cc78be718c8154ac80d1ae2;

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

If the cookie is set for the domain pix-all.com, then it will always be sent in requests to static.pix-all.com because static.pix-all.com is a subdomain of pix-all.com

So what is the problem? You're having issues because the cookie works as it's supposed to?

Comment: my understating is that if you set the cookie domain to "pix-all.com" it should be sent only for this domain and if ".pix-all.com" then it should be sent for this domain and its sub-domains. What am i missing here?

Comment: @Pablo the manual says `The domain that the cookie is available. To make the cookie available on all subdomains of example.com then you'd set it to '.example.com'. The . is not required but makes it compatible with more browsers. Setting it to www.example.com  will make the cookie only available in the www  subdomain. Refer to tail matching in the » spec for details. `